# What does Harmonica's brother say before he dies?

Tags: dialogue, once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

Here is the scene : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kD54-q1uFM

It is right before the final duel and lets the audience know Harmonica's motivation in wanting to kill Frank.

Harmonica's brother is standing on Harmonicas shoulders with a noose around his neck. Harmonica is the only thing keeping him alive. Franks gang are present and knowing that there's no way he can get out of this alive he kicks Harmonica to the ground.

Right before he kicks Harmonica away he says something but we can't hear it. Does anyone know what he says?

Comment: the video has been taken down

Comment: could you possibly tell the time frame around which the scene occurs? that would be helpful to locate the scene elsewhere.

Comment: Thats strange. The link works for me. Ill look up the times when I get a chance

Comment: @Travis Harmonica's brother starts to speak the line in question, at approximately 2:22:27 in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Sergio Leone Web Board](http://www.fistful-of-leone.com/forums/index.php?threadid=240;start=0):

> I've seen OUATITW close to 100 times.  I saw it at the theater in 1969.  My best opinion on what the brother says to Frank is  "You sick son of a bitch....I'll show you."

Comment: It does look like the first part of what he says is "You sick son of a bitch"... however, we must remember that Sergio Leone films are made with people who often did not all speak the same language.  In almost every case, the movie was filmed silently, and the dialog was added in later during post production.  This would mean that an actor would often deliver their dialog in the language they spoke.  The actor playing Harmonica's brother, in that scene, could have been speaking Spanish, Italian, or English.

Comment: @Bon Gart The brother is played by Claudio Mancini, a producer of this movie and many others, so not an actor.